# Historical bid/ask prices

Tags: historical-trade-data

I'm searching for BTC historical prices and people often link this source: http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/

Now, I'm familiar with forex historical prices where I have tick or OHLC data with bid/ask prices. However, data from that website have 3 columns (timestamp, price and amount?).

Is there a way I can get/extract historical bid/ask prices from data available on http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/? If not, is there a (preferably free) source of BTC historical bid/ask prices (at least for the H1 timeframe)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.

Each exchange that deals in bitcoins has it's own pricing, there is no single exchange from which to draw data.

The exchanges may or may not have have an api to access their pricing history with, you would need to check that exchange to see.

https://btc-e.com/api/documentation is one such exchange, but they don't appear to have their trade history available, for example.